# Permission denied when performing a DNS lookup on OpenShift Online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, openshift

I am trying to look up a DNS record in my Rails application on OpenShift Online. Unfortunately this fails with a Permission denied error. From the logs:

```
[App 13739 stdout] I, [2015-01-24T13:37:47.698714 #13739]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms
[App 13739 stdout] F, [2015-01-24T13:37:47.811394 #13739] FATAL -- : 
[App 13739 stdout] Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - bind(2)):
[App 13739 stdout]   app/models/user.rb:706:in `block in validate_mail_domain'
[App 13739 stdout]   app/models/user.rb:705:in `validate_mail_domain'
```

The failing code is:

```
  def validate_mail_domain
    begin
      Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
        dns.getresource(mail.split("@").last, Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::SOA)
      end
    rescue ArgumentError
      errors.add(:mail, "must be provided")
    rescue Resolv::ResolvError
      errors.add(:mail, "must be valid")
    end
  end
```

where line 706 is the one beginning with `dns.getresource`.

(The logic is simple: A domain that exists will have an SOA record. If there is none, then the domain is not valid.)

This is pretty standard stuff, and this failure here is quite unexpected. Is there some other way that I should be performing DNS lookups within OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't do DNS lookups on OpenShift due to an SELinux restriction. You can confirm this with `dig` when you SSH into your gear:

```
$ dig google.com
dig: isc_socket_bind: permission denied
```

This restriction is documented in this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=885933), and the linked OpenShift forums [thread](https://forums.openshift.com/dns-lookup-gives-permission-denied-error) recommends you to use an external web-based DNS lookup service as a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: This does appear to be the case. The workaround of using a web-based service seems (1) really kludgey and (2) unlikely to make me any friends, as most such services that I looked at don't want automated queries and don't provide an API.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bummer. I think this restriction is related to binding a UDP port? And have you looked at http://www.statdns.com/api/?